# What are some good services or tools to use for remote pair programming?

Tags: tdd, bdd, pair-programming

I have used screen sharing (via Skype and joinme), as well as tmux.

tmux provides a more interactive experience, but I find the delay to be annoying.

What are the best services and tools to use for remote pair programming?

Preferably working in Sublime Text 2, but if that is not feasable then vim is fine.

By "best" I mean:

- Responsive - I don't want to have to wait to see the effect of my key strokes
- Interactive - It should be easy to switch control to the other person

Working in Ruby, Rails, Sublime Text 2, (perhaps) vim.

**EDIT:** Needs to run on OSX (preferably) or Ubuntu. Please note whether the solution runs on a local machine (and there is a way for other people to connect to it without a valid internet IP) or if the solution runs on a sever with a valid internet static IP.

Comment: I don't do remote pair programming very often, but last time I tried tmux+vim I didn't experience much delay. Just saying...

Comment: Interesting question, but isn't recommendation of software and services considered off-topic?

Comment: @exebook - Not really. But when I asked this question there were no Online Code Editors. Now they are common and free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For pair programming, I've used [Screen](http://kb.iu.edu/data/acuy.html) and [SubEthaEdit](http://www.codingmonkeys.de/subethaedit/) usually in combination with voice chat, such as Skype.

Answer (score 1):

I like TeamViewer myself.  You could also look at Mikogo

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Nitrous](http://www.nitrous.io)?  It's a web-based IDE that includes a terminal/bash and a text-editor.  You can sign up for free and enter collaborative mode, invite your collaborator and away you go.